# Juniper SRX 240H latency going on with HA Cluster. Are there any steps to troubleshoot the issue?

Tags: juniper, juniper-srx

Currently we are having a latency issue between a Juniper HA cluster and a Cisco switch c3750. We have LACP configured between them.

```
reth3 { vlan-tagging; redundant-ether-options { redundancy-group 1; minimum-links 1; lacp { active; periodic slow)
```

Should I make the periodic option faster?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does the network look like, what are the network device configurations, and what do you have that shows the problem, etc.

Comment: I have ethechannel configured between cisco switch(3750) and juniper srx 240 cluster so we have one client generating high amount of traffic if we put that client on maitenence mode I don't see any latency but I cant do this for long please let me know if you need any cli output

Comment: Yes, the network device configurations. Copy the configurations, paste them into your question, and use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`) on them. We need to know the interfaces connected.

Comment: there are 2ge interface connected to lacp ge-0/0/8 to 9. I setup the lacp last year and since we never had any issue but today there is some issue with lantency going on due to the high amount of traffic

Comment: Just edit the question to include everything. We have some Juniper guys that show up from time to time, and a lot of Cisco guys that are always around.

Comment: reth3 {
        vlan-tagging;
        redundant-ether-options {
            redundancy-group 1;
            minimum-links 1;
            lacp {
                active;
                periodic slow;

Comment: shall i make it periodic faster ?

Comment: Instead of trying to put things in comments, edit your question to include all the information. You can format it there, and your character limit is 30,000 characters, rather than the few hundred in a comment.

Comment: Changing the LACP timers will have no bearing at all on latency.  It sounds like your host is potentially overwhelming the SRX with traffic.

Comment: thanks for the update. it was one of the web server traffic choking the srx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for the update. it was one of the web server traffic choking the srx

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.